# How to convert 1D numpy arrays element-wire into new 1D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I've `n` numpy 1D arrays `ì_0 = [i00, i01, i02, ...]`, `i_1 = [i10, i11, i12, ...]`, ... and would like to put the values into `m` new 1D arrays `o_0 = [i00, i10, 120, ...]`, `o_1 = [i01, i11, i21, ...]`, ... where `m` is the element count of the equal length arrays `i_0`, `i_1`, ... . How can I achieve this as performant as possible (potentially enabling Python laziness when iterating over the `o_0`, `o_1`, ... arrays)?

Consider this examplary input data `i_0` (upcasted), `i_1`

```
import numpy as np

i_0 = np.array([1.0, 2, 3])
i_1 = np.array([1.1, 2.1, 3.1])
```

which shall be transformed into the `m=3` outputs `o_0`, `o_1` and `o_2`

```
o_0 = np.array([1.0, 1.1])
o_1 = np.array([2.0, 2.1])
o_2 = np.array([3.0, 3.1])
```

or into a 2D array `o`

```
o = np.array([[1.0, 1.1], [2.0, 2.1], [3.0, 3.1]])
```

which is equivalent to

```
o = np.array([o_0, o_1, o_2])
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code example with input and desired output?

Comment: Let's take float as element data types. Actual values are irrelevant. In case the ocnversion is wrapped into a function the output cold be provided as 2D array (`[o_0, 0_1, ...]`).

Comment: Sry, typo. For the output I meant a 2D array like `[o_0, o_1, ..., o_(m-1)]`

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean exactly. You could add an example to you post (use the edit button instead of adding more comments), with an example array of just two or three elements and then the output for that input. Something people could actually run is always good. In general, if you want to iterate over all the elements individually, you might not need NumPy and could get better performance from basic python lists.

Comment: @n1k31t4 I added the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a question: why element-wise? Do you want to do things to each point on its way from input to output array? If so, you either need to simply loop over input arrays and maybe use python's `yield` (saving maybe on working memory). Alternatively, if possible, you can encompass your steps into a single function to vectorize the operations and so execute on a complete numpy array in one go (element-wise).

#### Edit:

In this case (your specific example) it is actually very easy, because you can join the input arrays into a single matrix oike this:

```
input = np.vstack([i_0, i_1])
```

And now simple transpose the matrix, in order to get your result:

```
result = input.T
```

To extract the arrays from the vector again, you can *unpack* them like this:

```
o_1, o_2 = result    # 2 output arrays for input arrays, each of 2 elements
```

You could use a python *list comprehension* or similar to do this for a matrix that actually has many more input/output vectors.

---

This answer is specific to your case, but hopefully demonstrates how `numpy` arrays can be used to perform operations in a single call (or a few) compared to languages like C/C++ where you iterate over each element. Under the hood, this is what numpy is doing for you (actually in C), so you get C-like performance in python. You maybe need to change your way if thinking when using numpy if you are familiar with low level languages.

Comment: You are right, conversion shall not take place element-wise but for all elements. I improved the question accordingly.

Comment: If I run `o_1, o_2 = result` I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Comment: How would equivalent code look like when using pandas DataFrame instead of numpy arrays? DataFrames are not as perfomant as arrays are I guess...

Comment: @thinwybk - Pandas dataframes hold a basic numpy array under the hood, so you can use the same code as above, specifying the arrays of your dataframe `df` like this: `df.values`.